# Applying condition while importing the data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with Laravel Excel Imports https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/

With the help of this, i have written AccessoryImport.php

I want to import my csv file which takes three input - vendor name, barcode and description..

Vendor name is being stored in vendor table and cooresponding id is being stored in accessory table.

But if vendor already exists, just fetch that id instead of creating new vendor in vendor table.

I have applied condition and all but still duplicate entries are being made in my database.

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Accessory;
use App\AccessoryVendor;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class AccessoryImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow
{
   public function collection(Collection $rows)
   {
       foreach($rows as $row)
       {
           $vendor = AccessoryVendor::where('name', '=', $row['vendor'])->get();
           //return $vendor;
           if($vendor === null) {
               $newvendor = AccessoryVendor::create([
                   'name' => $row['vendor'],
               ]);
   
               Accessory::create([
                   'vendor_id'     => $newvendor->id,
                   'description'    => $row['description'], 
                   'barcode' => $row['barcode'],
               ]);
           } 
           else 
           { 
               Accessory::create([
                   'vendor_id'     => $vendor->id,
                   'description'    => $row['description'], 
                   'barcode' => $row['barcode'],
               ]);
           } 
       } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the firstOrCreate() Eloquent method - it will find the model if it exists, and create it if not, returning it either way.

Comment: Can you explain it more ? How can i do this with firstorcreate ?? Accessory Vendor i have to check from accessoryvendor table and then on the basis of it, if it exits i have to fetch vendor id and then store it in accessory table.

Comment: The Laravel documentation is very good - I suggest you start there. In particular here : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models - rather than the first chunk of code (checking if model exists or not, then creating it if it does not, a simple firstOrCreate will combine all that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do it like this:

```
$checkIfVendorExists = AccessoryVendor::where('name', '=', $row['vendor'])->first();

if ($checkIfVendorExists !== null) {
  
        Accessory::create([
                   'vendor_id' => $checkIfVendorExists->id,
                   'description' => $row['description'], 
                   'barcode' => $row['barcode'],
               ]);

}
```

If vendor names are unique, then you should use `->first()` instead of `->get()` when trying to check for existing records.